# Should I extend this class or just use it?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I am writing helper classes for a large project in PHP and I have written a class called `Command`.  It is essentially an OOP wrapper around running system commands from PHP in a controlled way.  It has methods like `addOption()` to add -a type options and `addArgument()` to add other arguments.

I will need to do a lot of scp'ing of files around so I will be using the Command class a lot.  The calls to scp are very specific in that I need certain options used every time.

Does it make sense to extend this class and create a `ScpCommand` class?  It seems to have an 'is a' relationship, but it is really just the same thing as the `Command` class with specific options every time.  I don't really think I would need to override any methods with the exception of the constructor.  I probably would add just class variables.  It would really just be a convenience.

What makes the most sense here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just configuration, why not consider a factory which returns a Command after doing your boiler-plate configuration for you?

```
function getScpCommand($???) 
{
    $Command = new Command();
    $Command->addOption(/* scp specific this */);
    $Command->addArgument(/* scp specific that */);
    /* etc */
    $Command->addOption(/* handle your getScpCommand parameters here */)

    return $Command;
}
```

Comment: I agree I think you could easily make a good argument for using Factory.  Nice thought.

Comment: Is it truly a factory if I'm not using subclasses?  Does it really matter?

Comment: I don't think it really matters - if it fits as a solution then use it. Don't get too hung up on pattern definitions.

Comment: I ended up extending the class anyways because I had an execute() method that needed to be overridden because of the nature of the scp call. =)